# Black screen at boot for Ubuntu MATE 20.04 beta 1 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 20.04, screen, raspberrypi, beta

.

Hello,

I have tried running Ubuntu MATE 20.04 beta 1, on my Raspberry Pi 4. During boot up, it only shows a black screen. And although the light shows activity, nothing seems to display on this black screen.

Is this a known issue?

Cheers,

Eddie.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was editing `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt` and adding:

```
hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the version compatible with Raspberry Pi, then your problem might have something to do with the HDMI settings in your [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/). Check [these](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38655/black-screen-on-first-boot-of-ubuntu-mate) [answers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=136049) and see if they work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it is the Raspberry 4 compatible version. Turns out things where just being displayed via the other HDMI port, and changes I tried in config.txt were not required after all. Strange, as this was the HDMI port the Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi install was using on the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the config.txt.
Changing "dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d" to "dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d" resolved the issue.